# What is the meaning of lagrange multiplier (especially in ramsey problem)

Tags: macroeconomics, lagrangian

Consider lagrange function for ramsey problem:
$L=E_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \{u(c,l)+\gamma_t (s^t)[E_0 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \beta^j u_c (s^{t+j}) z(s^{t+j}) -u_c (s^t) b_t(s^{t+1})] \}$
where $[E_0 \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \beta^j u_c (s^{t+j}) z(s^{t+j}) -u_c (s^t) b_t(s^{t+1})]$ means "net surplus - net debt" of government.

In sargent's book(Recursive macroeconomics) it says
if government is borrowing(bond issue) then lagrange multiplier $\gamma_t (s^t)$ is positive 
and if government accumulates asset then lagrange multiplier $\gamma_t (s^t)$ is negative.
I don't know how to determine that sign.
What is the meaning of lagrange multiplier in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of a simple utility maximization, the lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ is the marginal utility of income. The rate of increase in utility as income increases. Check this [references](http://the%20rate%20of%20increase%20in%20maximized%20utility%20as%20income%20increases.) for more details.

In the specific case of the Ramsey Cass Koopmans model, The Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ measures the marginal value of wealth (or resources) in period
t. if we exogenously give the economy $\epsilon$ units of the good during period $t$, where $\epsilon$ is small enough, welfare increases by approximately $\lambda\epsilon$.
You may refer to the following [lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/economics/14-05-intermediate-macroeconomics-spring-2013/lecture-notes/MIT14_05S13_LecNot_Ramsey.pdf) for more clarity.